# Tsql VarChar implicitly to SmallDateTime

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, varchar, smalldatetime

When executing the following  using a smalldatetime constraint on the returned results, I get zero results:

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '01/01/1900'
```

**or**

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '1900-01-01'
```

**But when using the following varchar argument all the sudden i get results which correspond to 1 Jan 2000. Does smalldatetime implicit conversion not work for mm/dd/YYYY dates and only mm/dd/YY dates?**

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '01/01/00'
```

This returns all results for 01/01/2000 birthdays!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_proc] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @DateOfBirth SmallDateTime = null 

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM
        view_People
    WHERE
        FirstName LIKE '%' + IsNull(@FName ,FirstName) + '%'
    AND
        LastName LIKE '%' + IsNull(@LName,LastName) + '%'
    AND
        DOB = IsNull(@DateOfBirth,DOB) 
    AND
        SSN = IsNull(@SSN,SSN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"01/01/00" is converted based on the "[two digit year cutoff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189577(SQL.90).aspx)" option.
So it becomes 01 Jan 2000.

If you send '1900-01-01', then your code shows you'll only get results if you have DOB =  01 Jan 1900.

Other than that, it's working as advertised.
Unless you want to run `Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth = DEFAULT` to force DOB to be ignored

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you should be comparing the output of:

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '01/01/00'
```

to:

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '01/01/2000'
```

or

```
Execute sp_proc @DateOfBirth =   '2000-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

use a safe format like YYYYMMDD (no dashes)

run these also to see what happens

```
select convert(smalldatetime,'19000101')
select convert(smalldatetime,'01/01/00')
select convert(smalldatetime,0)
```